# Is it possible to handle null and false differently in mustache (or hogan)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache, hogan.js

I have some data which (quite reasonably) uses null and false for different meanings.

Eg, a test which has failed is false, whereas one which has not completed is null.

I understand mustache sections treat null/false the same in most cases. Is there any way I can make mustache (or hogan, more specifically, which is the implementation I'm using) treat null  and false differently?

Or should I hack in some additional boolean for 'tests in progress' or somesuch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all falsey values are interpreted as false in the Mustache spec [[1]](https://github.com/mustache/spec/tree/master/specs), with the exception of the empty string which most javascript implementations interpret as falsey but Hogan gets it as truthy [[2]](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/issues/48) (because the canon Ruby implementation does it like that, and the spec omits the empty string so implementors are free to interpret at will).

So in short, `null` and `false` are the same in Mustache and Hogan, you will need another property to convey this differentiation.